# Svg file into Media Library

Tags: svg, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a responsive design Sitecore 7 solution, I want to add svg files into Media Library to be processed exactly like jpg,jpeg pictures. When I upload svg files they are processed like media file not like image files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I know Sitecore CMS does not support SVG images out of the box.
You are right, if you upload a SVG image, Sitecore will not process it as an image, but processes as a common media file. Thumbnails generation also does not work for a SVG image.
Please try use the following media type definition for SVG type:

```
<mediaType name="SVG image" extensions="svg">
  <mimeType>image/svg+xml</mimeType>
  <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
  <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/image</sharedTemplate>
  <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/image</versionedTemplate>
  <mediaValidator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageValidator"/>
  <thumbnails>
    <generator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageThumbnailGenerator, Sitecore.Kernel">
      <extension>png</extension>
    </generator>
    <width>150</width>
    <height>150</height>
    <backgroundColor>#FFFFFF</backgroundColor>
  </thumbnails>
 </mediaType>
```

Also please register mime types for svg files into configuration files.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
     <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are correct if all you want is to be able to *upload* SVG files to the media library. If you then want to *use* the SVGs in the media library within the Sitecore Rich Text Editor, there are additional steps that must be followed, otherwise you will get a "selected item is not an image" error.

This blog post explains the RTE customizations that are required to use SVG within the rich text editor.
http://sitecorecorner.com/2015/11/23/sitecore-svg-support/

Answer (score 2):

As of Sitecore 8.1 Update 2, the configuration update is included by default. Tests passed in Media Library upload and RTE fields, as well as with GlassMapper.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig">
    <sitecore>
        <mediaLibrary>
            <mediaTypes>
                <mediaType name="SVG image" extensions="svg">
                    <mimeType>image/svg+xml</mimeType>
                    <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
                    <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/image</sharedTemplate>
                    <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/image</versionedTemplate>
                    <mediaValidator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageValidator"/>
                    <thumbnails>
                        <generator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageThumbnailGenerator, Sitecore.Kernel">
                            <extension>png</extension>
                        </generator>
                        <width>150</width>
                        <height>150</height>
                        <backgroundColor>#FFFFFF</backgroundColor>
                    </thumbnails>
                </mediaType>
            </mediaTypes>
        </mediaLibrary>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```